# GKE Loadbalancer how to add SSL Certs

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a service of ingress type LoadBalancer.

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

GKE create a loadbalancer and forwarding rules. The Load Balancer created by GKE/GCloud is tcp. I want Google Managed SSL Certs. I created the certs using gcloud

```
gcloud beta compute ssl-certificates create...
```

How do I attach this cert to the LoadBalancer defined by GKE. 
There is no section in the console to edit the load balancer/front end to add SSL certs? Can I do it using the gcloud CLI

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to terminate SSL on your GCE load balancer it can't be a TCP load balancer because a TCP load balancer is a Layer 4 load balancer, and SSL is at layer 7 in the network stack. For this type of load balancer, you can set up a Kubernetes [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) with an ingress controller like [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) or [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/) and terminate SSL on the Ingress.

GCE support layer 7 load balancers but they are not supported in Kubernetes yet (afaik). However, you could actually terminate SSL on GCE if you'd like to, by provisioning an [HTTPS or L7](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https) load balancer, but you will have to manually point it to a Kubernetes [Service of the NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type.

Update:

Another [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) about Ingresses with Google managed SSL certs.

Comment: Thanks, I did try with the ingress resource and installing SSL (lets encrypt). This confirms what we saw, the Loadbalancer creates a TCP LB

Comment: Here's another doc article talking about setting up Ingresses with Google-managed SSL certificates on GKE: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs